# Mysql - update table column from another column based on order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with columns `id, name, position, old_position`.

The column `old_position` contains unique numbers that are used to define the order when making select. But the numbers are not consecutive(even if when ordered). E.g. 
2, 12, 11, 14, 20, 35, 45, 28,

What I am trying to achieve is to populate the column `position` with consecutive numbers starting from 1, but with the same order according to old_position, so when I order by `position ASC` still I can get the same order of rows. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using the values for ordering, why do you care if they are consecutive?

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually the case was a little more complicated and localized, just wanted to keep the question simple. but im sure this is what I need. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is unique for each row, you can do this with variables:

```
update <table> t join
       (select t.id, @rn := @rn + 1 as seqnum
        from <table> t cross join (select @rn := 0) vars
        order by old_position
       ) tt
       on tt.id = t.id
    set t.position = tt.seqnum;
```

If you wanted, you can write this without the subquery.  The challenge is defining the variable.  Here is one method:

```
update <table> t
    set t.position = (@rn := coalesce(@rn, 0) + 1)
    order by old_position;
```

You can't initialize the variable in a subquery because MySQL doesn't permit both `join` and `order by` in an `update` statement.

Comment: cool !! it worked , very nice. btw, `update table t` should be `update t`, got an error when trying. thank u

Comment: @dav . . . I just use "table" as a generic table name when questions don't provide one.  It seems to be a bad habit.